# How do I format a string from a string with %@ in Swift

Tags: swift

I am using Swift 4.2.  I am getting extraneous characters when formatting one string (s1) from another string(s0) using the %@ format code.

I have searched extensively for details of string formatting but have come up with only partial answers including the code in the second line below. I need to be able to format s1 so that I can customize output from a Swift process. I ask this because I have not found an answer while searching for ways to format a string from a string.

I tried the following three statements:

```
let s0:[String] = ["abcdef"]

let s1:[String] = [String(format:"%@",s0)]

print(s1)
...
```

The output is shown below. It may not be clear, here, but there are four leading spaces to the left of the abcdef string.

```
["(\n      abcdef\n)"]
```

How can I format s1 so it does not include the brackets, the \n escape characters, and the leading spaces?

Comment: Youre storing everything as string arrays and using that in the format so you’re relying on whatever the default system description of that for the output. if you want to output `abcdef` just store it as a string

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `String(format:"%@", s0)`? If `s0` where a string (which it’s not in your example, but let’s assume it was), the `String(format:"%@", s0)` would be another string that is the same as `s0`. You’re using `String(format:)` but aren’t doing any formatting. What precisely are you trying to accomplish with `String(format:)`?

Comment: What I am trying to do is build an understanding of formatting.  I'm coming from the perspective of using a printf statement, where string might be formatted with , lets say...  printf("here is a string %s, and here is an integer %i", etc.  It seems to me there should be a similar syntax in Swift, but so far I've not found it.

Comment: If `foo` is the string, and `bar` is the integer, it’s `print("here is a string \(foo), and here is an integer \(bar)")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting extraneous characters when formatting one string (`s1`) from another string (`s0`) ...

The `s0` is not a string. It is an array of strings (i.e. the square brackets of `[String]` indicate an array and is the same as saying `Array<String>`). And your `s1` is also array, but one that that has one element, whose value is the string representation of the entire `s0` array of strings. That’s obviously not what you intended.

> How can I format s1 so it does not include the brackets, the `\n` escape characters, and the leading spaces?

You’re getting those brackets because `s1` is an array. You’re getting the string with the `\n` and spaces because its first value is the string representation of yet another array, `s0`.

So, if you’re just trying to format a string, `s0`, you can do:

```
let s0: String = "abcdef"
let s1: String = String(format: "It is ‘%@’", s0)
```

Or, if you really want an array of strings, you can call `String(format:)` for each using the `map` function:

```
let s0: [String] = ["abcdef", "ghijkl"]
let s1: [String] = s0.map { String(format: "It is ‘%@’", $0) }
```

By the way, in the examples above, I didn’t use a string format of just `%@`, because that doesn’t accomplish anything at all, so I assumed you were formatting the string for a reason.

---

FWIW, we generally don’t use `String(format:)` very often. Usually we do “string interpolation”, with `\(` and `)`:

```
let s0: String = "abcdef"
let s1: String = "It is ‘\(s0)’"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are using an array but a string in s0.

so the following index will help you.

```
let s0:[String] = ["abcdef"]

let s1:[String] = [String(format:"    %@",s0[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the unneccessary arrays and let the compiler figure out the types:

```
let s0 = "abcdef" // a string

let s1 = String(format:"- %@ -",s0) // another string

print(s1) // prints "- abcdef -"
```